# Upgrading Ubuntu through updates

Tags: upgrade

I would like to know if upgrading Ubuntu from 12.04 to 12.10 via update is actually downloading the complete 12.10 OS or its just the necessary files.

Thank you

Comment: I can not explain it better than the image in the answer here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/94817/what-happens-during-a-package-upgrade

Answer (score 2):

The mentioned image says everything better than i will now, but still...

It will only download the new packages which are needed, which may be a lot but only them.